# if conditions for matching predictions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have opened a soccer prediction sites.
I am using excel to calculate all the scores submitted by users.
Users are more than 500 so i need to have formulas.

Match 1 : Manchester United vs Chelsea 
Exact Score 2-1
Required Conditions
Exact Predictions (thats 2-1) = 6 points
Wrong predictions but correct outcome (thats if user submitted 4-0, which is man utd winning) = 3 points
Wrong prediction but user submitting winning team score just by difference(thats if user submits a score like 1-0, 4-3, 5-4, which is just a goal difference) = 3 points.
If totaly wrong prediction = 0 points

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you :)

```
=IF(AND($H$3=B3,$I$3=C3), "6",IF(XOR(AND($H$3>$I$3,B3>C3),AND($I$3>$H$3,C3>B3)),"3", IF($H$3-$I$3=B3-C3,"3","0")))
```

[image: example]